# Which verb form do I use for a future action?

Tags: verbs, tenses

Which sentence below is correct?

“I’m going to open up a store when I grow up, and so **is** my brother.”

“I’m going to open up a store when I grow up, and so **will** my brother.”

If both are correct, presumably there is a subtle difference which can be explained.

Answer (score 1):

The verb following 'so' must match the first one.

“I’m (I **am) going** to open up a store when I grow up, and **so is** my brother.”

or

“I **will open** up a store when I grow up, and **so will** my brother.”